# Find text in existing pdf then change it to current date (keep the text location) ? c#

Tags: c#, itext

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdf, pageNumber, strategy);                
System.Text.StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdf, 1));
currentPageText.Replace(date_only, "mama");
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

#### Your code

Your code

```
string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdf, pageNumber, strategy);
```

**extracts** the text from some page. You do not get a *representation* of the text on a page which you can manipulate to change the text on the page. All you get is an independent `string` *copy* of everything iText recognized as text on the given page.

Thus, your code

```
currentPageText.Replace(date_only, "mama");
```

only replaces characters in that independent `string`, it does nothing in the PDF.

#### Your task

Your task

> Find text in existing pdf then change it to current date (keep the text location)

is not trivial to implement for these (and other) reasons:

- in a PDF what to you appears as a connected word or sentence, might actually be the result of several independent drawing instructions in an non-intuitive order spread all over the page content instruction stream or even across multiple content instruction streams;
- the text to replace might be drawn using an embedded font subset which does not contain glyphs required for your replacement text;
- text pieces in PDF often is drawn at fixed positions; if you replace one string by another one, the result may be overlapping texts (if the replacement is larger) or big gaps (if it is smaller).

One option for you is to find the original text including coordinates (if you search, you'll find many questions and answers on that topic on stack overflow), draw a white rectangle over it and draw new text in that area.

Instead of simply covering the original text you might want to use the iText redaction feature to actually remove it.

Actually, though, the better option would be to redefine your task. E.g. use PDF form fields to fill in instead of text to replace.